# Can't update column values, it is associated with a clustered index?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am having some problems when trying to update column values, this column has a clustered index associated to it.

This is the update statement.

```
UPDATE  dbo.VentureXRef
SET     RefValue = REPLICATE('0',7 - LEN(RefValue)) + RefValue WHERE   LEN(RefValue) < 7
```

This is the error I get

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'dbo.VentureXRef' with unique
>   index 'idx_WFHMJVXRef_RefValueByType'.

This is mytable definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VentureXRef]
(
[ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
[RefValue] [varchar] (30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[RefValueTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[State] [char] (2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__WFHMJoint__State__2AC11801] DEFAULT (' '),
[ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DoingBusinessAs] [varchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[Disabled] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_VentureXRef_Disabled] DEFAULT (0),
[Username] [varchar] (64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_VentureXRef_Username] DEFAULT (user_name()),
[DateDeleted] [datetime] NULL,
[DateLastModified] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_VentureXRef_DateLastModified] DEFAULT (getdate())
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [idx_WFHMJVXRef_RefValue] ON [dbo].[VentureXRef] ([RefValue], [State]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VentureXRef] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__WFHMJointVenture__28D8CF8F] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED  ([ID]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_WFHMJVXRef_RefValueByType] ON [dbo].[VentureXRef] ([RefValue], [State], [DateDeleted], [RefValueTypeID]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VentureXRef] ADD CONSTRAINT [IX_VentureXRef] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED  ([RefValue], [RefValueTypeID], [State], [DateDeleted]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VentureXRef] ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_WFHMJVXRef_ClientID] FOREIGN KEY ([ClientID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([ClientID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VentureXRef] ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_WFHMJVXRef_RefValueTypeID] FOREIGN KEY ([RefValueTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[VentureRefValueType] ([RefValueTypeID])
GO
```

What is the proper way to do this update statement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

YOur problem is you are trying to update it to a value that already exists in the table and so the unique index says it can't.

Comment: But right now column refvalue allows to have same data in different records, I mean those are not unique, as this result set shows

RefValue
038058
038058
038059
038059
038059
038060
038060
038060

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by HILGEm this is a duplicate records problem.To identify records causing duplication you can run below query after substituting your table and database name in place of CTE

```
use test;
with cte as (
select '123' refvalue union all select '567' union all
select '0000123' union all 
select '123456')

select refvalue from cte as a
where 
len(refvalue) <7 and
exists(
select 1 from cte as b where
len(refvalue)>=7 and
REPLICATE('0',7 - LEN(a.RefValue)) + a.RefValue =b.refvalue
)
```

Comment: I ran the query and I got '0033520' so I updated it to '033520' and re-ran the query, I think it should be fine since now that repeated value does not exist right? but I still getting same error

Comment: First of all the query cannot report 0033520 because the query only reports cases where length(refvalue)<7 .What the query implies is that there exists more than 1 record which ends in 33520.Since your update will  set all these to 0033520 you end up with duplicates.So you need to search for records that end in 33520 (LIKE '%33520') , decide which one to keep an delete the restt